# matplotlib not will be installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I have a PyCharm Community Edition , and I would work with matplotlib's module , but I found a problem when I want to install it
[image]

My question is how can I install it with a pip version located at : '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6' ?

Thank you

Comment: Read the error message. Your *Python interpreter* is located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`. `pip` is in the same directory. The reason matplotlib can't be installed is stated very clearly - you don't have freetype installed properly. Amazingly, on the front page of the matplotlib website is a big ol' link to the installation instructions, which includes directions on building from source and a special section on building under OS X. Do some googling and searching of questions here and elsewhere to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I check this website before I ask here… when I put : pip3 install matplotlib I had this error message:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6l/2k5789s52fg35kj2y4bjpknw0000gn/T/pip-build-1o03mv1u/matplotlib/

Comment: Which is why you need to build it from source *after* you have correctly installed freetype and its development headers, which is what I said in the first place.